# HOC in webpack throws Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**Some context**

1. I have a HOC called withCtx. It provides context to underlying Comps
2. I have a working solution at the end of this post, but it's way too much extra code just for a HOC.

**The issue**

I'm experiencing this issue only within my npm library built with Webpack 4. In the app, the exact same export of the HOC works great.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

**My guesses:**

Webpack seems to pass functions to the HOC while the app seems to pass objects (React Components).

So I guess I'm missing a plugin in Webpack, or I should add a conditional statement in the HOC in order to render its passed Component the right way.

Here's the HOC:

```js
export const withCtx = contextTypes => Component => {
    /* The context is passed as props. This way the component is
   completely decoupled from the context API.
  */

    console.log('typeof ----------', Component);
    const ContextConsumer = (props, context) => <Component {...props} {...context} />;
    ContextConsumer.contextTypes = contextTypes;

    return ContextConsumer;
};
```

This does NOT work with webpack

```js
export default withCtx({
    nextRouter: PropTypes.object,
    currentRoute: PropTypes.object,
})(Toolbar);
```

**This DOES work with webpack (why not the above?)**

```js
const Toolbar_Extended = props => {
    const TB = withCtx({
        nextRouter: PropTypes.object,
        currentRoute: PropTypes.object,
    })(Toolbar);
    return <TB {...props} />;
};
export default Toolbar_Extended;
```

**And this DOES work as well...**

```js
export const withCtx = contextTypes => Component => {
    /* The context is passed as props. This way the component is
   completely decoupled from the context API.
  */

    let ContextConsumer = (props, context) => <Component {...props} {...context} />;

    ContextConsumer.contextTypes = contextTypes;

    if (typeof Component == 'function') {
        return props => {
            return <ContextConsumer {...props} />;
        };
    }

    return ContextConsumer;
};

// then
export default props => withCtx({
        nextRouter: PropTypes.object,
        currentRoute: PropTypes.object,
    })(Toolbar)(props);
```

Could someone enlighten me on this?

Why do I pass PropTypes? Because I handle context this way. But whatever the HOC, I get the error message. With or without PropTypes...

```js
// Providing HOCs you can easily solve the code fragility problem of the React context. You’ll only need to update one place if the API changes. Let’s illustrate a possible implementation:

const provideContext = 
  (childContextTypes, getChildContext) => (Component) => {
    class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
      static childContextTypes = childContextTypes;
      getChildContext = () => getChildContext(this.props);

      render() {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
    return ContextProvider;
  };

const consumeContext = (contextTypes) => (Component) => {
  /* The context is passed as props. This way the component is
   completely decoupled from the context API.
  */ 
  const ContextConsumer = (props, context) =>
    <Component {...props} {...context} />;
  ContextConsumer.contextTypes = contextTypes;
  return ContextConsumer;
};

// Then, you can use it as follows:

const Child = ({color}) => (
  <div style={{backgroundColor: color}}>
    Hello context!!!
  </div>
);

const ChildwithContext = consumeContext({
  color: React.PropTypes.string
})(Child);

const MiddleComponent = () => <ChildwithContext />;

const App = provideContext(
  {color: React.PropTypes.string},
  () => ({color: 'red'})
)(MiddleComponent);
```

And here's my webpack config

common config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');

// Is the current build a development build
const IS_DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
var root = __dirname;

// Directories
const dirNode = 'node_modules';
const dirApp = path.join(root, 'src');
const dirAssets = path.join(root, 'assets');

// Optimizations
const dependencies = Object.keys(require('./package.json').dependencies);

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

let config = {
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(root, './src/index')
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [dirNode, dirApp, dirAssets],
        alias: {
            // irrelevant to this question
        }
    },
    target: 'node',
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async',
            minSize: 30000,
            maxSize: 0,
            minChunks: 1,
            maxAsyncRequests: 5,
            maxInitialRequests: 3,
            automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
            name: true,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    priority: -10
                },
                default: {
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        // irrelevant to this question
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            // BABEL
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                options: {
                    compact: true
                }
            },
            // and much more ...
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Build config

```js
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',

        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        globalObject: 'this'
    },

    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])]
});
```

Comment: How are you importing the npm library? How are you building it? You should share your webpack config and the code that's getting the error. Usually that message indicates a mismatch in the export and import, so we'll need to see what you're transpiling ES6-style modules to in the npm package.

Comment: Thanks for asking @Jacob I updated the question.